# How to call .html.erb file on button click using .ajax call?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

```
function myCall() {
    var request = $.ajax({
        url: "new.html.erb",
        type: "GET",            
        dataType: "html",
        success:function(data) {  
            $("#mybox").html(data);
        }
    });
```

}
        });

```
}
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Create User" onclick="myCall();">
```

I have a page in that i created a button when i click that button i called a javascript function which open a form(available in new.html.erb file) in div tag which is in current page using ajax. I used the above method but nothing happens on button click.

Comment: Can you please add a ```console.log('test');``` inside the function? If you run this code afterwards, do you get that test on the console and if so, is there a http request going on?

Comment: when i click on that nothing happens it is not redirecting after clicking nothing is going on